# HTML "bring to front" not using z-index

Tags: html, z-index

Is there a possiblility to bring a html element to front without increasing it's z-index? All elements having the same z-index overlap depending on there order in the DOM. I could remove the element and append it to it's parent again - but is there any nicer solution?

Edit:

Keeping an array of all rects, set all rect's z-index to x and the just hovered to x+1 does the trick, but needs an array.

Comment: Can you post some code we can fiddle with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably work if you wrote your HTML code from bottom positioning to top, since the browser reads the code from the top of the file to the bottom. Still, using `z-index` is a lot safer and more efficient.

Comment: In my scenario the user can place multiple rectangles in the document. The last one hovered should alway be on top - but never higher than several other elements in the document.

I could set the other element's z-index to "almost infinite" but I don't like these solutions. An other option would be decreasing all rectangle's z-index, that are not active atm. Guess that's a possible solution.

But rearranging the order of the siblings isn't possible at all (without removing / adding)?

Comment: You could try toggling their visibility with javascript, but I'm not sure if that would help. Although a very large z-index seems like bad coding procedure, it is pretty commonplace.

Comment: I don't want to hide them, the last one hovered just should be the topmost. So the best solution is to use two different z-indexes, set all inactive rectangles to the lower one and the hovered to the higher?

So I'd need to keep an array of all rectangles.

Comment: If two rectangles have the same z-index, does the most recent one become topmost on your code?

Comment: Yes, it does. But hovering the previous one with the mouse should bring it to front. I keep an array of all rects now, set all rect's z-index to x and the just hovered to x+1.

Does the trick, but needs an array.

Answer (score 1):

try following code:

```css
strong {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed;
  text-align: center;
}

.DivStatic {
  position: static;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ffc;
  border-color: #996;
}

.DivAbsolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #fdd;
  border-color: #900;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.DivRelative {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #cfc;
  border-color: #696;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#Main1 {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#Main2 {
  top: 30px;
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
}

#Main3 {
  top: 15px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
}

#Main4 {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

#Main5 {
  background-color: #ffc;
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Main1" class="DivAbsolute">
  <strong>First DIV #1</strong><br />position: absolute;</div>
<div id="Main2" class="DivRelative">
  <strong>Second DIV #2</strong><br />position: relative;</div>
<div id="Main3" class="DivRelative">
  <strong>Third DIV #3</strong><br />position: relative;</div>
<div id="Main4" class="DivAbsolute">
  <strong>Fourth DIV #4</strong><br />position: absolute;</div>
<div id="Main5" class="DivStatic">
  <strong>Fifth DIV #5</strong><br />position: static;</div>
```